# Android datepicker and timepicker issue

Tags: android, datetimepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

The problem that am facing is with the from-to date and time dialog's. I have created all of them separate.
On onCreate i have set the current date and time on the dialog's for the user. i.e for eg 24/7/2012 as todays date. When ever i change/click on the dialog for the from_date to the date for eg: 26/7/2012 then i have change the text of the to_date dialog to 26/7/2012 via setText. The issue that comes here is when i open the to_date dialog the date that appears in the dialog is 24/7/2012 and not 26/7/2012. How can this be achieved same for date and time picker dialog. I have attached the code below.
Thanks in advance.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_FROM:
        Log.i("Date Case", "" + from_day);
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListenerfrom, from_year,
                from_month, from_day);
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO:
        Log.i("Date Case", "" + to_day);
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListenerto, to_year,
                to_month, to_day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID_FROM:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListenerfrom, from_hours,
                from_min, false);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID_TO:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListenerto, to_hours, to_min,
                false);

    }
    return null;

}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListenerfrom = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        from_year = yr;
        from_month = monthOfYear;
        from_day = dayOfMonth;
        // to_year = yr;
        // to_month = monthOfYear;
        to_day = dayOfMonth;

        Log.i("From Day", "" + from_day);
        Log.i("To Day", "" + to_day);
        Log.i("To Cons", "" + dayOfMonth);

        try {
            updateDateFrom();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnCancelListener mDateFromCancelListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnCancelListener() {
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListenerto = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        to_year = yr;
        to_month = monthOfYear;
        to_day = dayOfMonth;

        Log.i("From Day", "" + from_day);
        Log.i("To Day", "" + to_day);
        Log.i("To Cons", "" + dayOfMonth);

        try {
            updateDateTo();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

private void updateDateFrom() throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    try {
        date_from = dateFormat.parse(from_day + "/" + from_month + "/"
                + from_year + " " + from_hours + ":" + to_min);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("From LONG   " + date_from.getTime());

    from_date_builder = new StringBuilder().append(from_day).append('/')
            .append(from_month + 1).append('/').append(from_year);

    from_date.setText(from_date_builder.toString());

    to_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(from_day).append('/')
            .append(from_month + 1).append('/').append(from_year));

}

private void updateDateTo() throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    try {
        date_to = dateFormat.parse(to_day + "/" + to_month + "/" + to_year
                + " " + to_hours + ":" + to_min);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("To LONG   " + date_to.getTime());

    if (date_from.getTime() <= date_to.getTime()) {
        to_date_builder = new StringBuilder().append(to_day).append('/')
                .append(to_month + 1).append('/').append(to_year);
        to_date.setText(to_date_builder.toString());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please set proper date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListenerfrom = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        from_hours = hourOfDay;
        from_min = minute;
        try {
            updateTimeFrom();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListenerto = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        to_hours = hourOfDay;
        to_min = minute;
        try {
            updateTimeTo();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private void updateTimeFrom() throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    time_from = dateFormat.parse(from_day + "/" + from_month + "/"
            + from_year + " " + from_hours + ":" + from_min);

    from_time_builder = new StringBuilder().append(from_hours).append(':')
            .append(from_min);

    from_time.setText(from_time_builder.toString());

    to_time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(from_hours).append(':')
            .append(from_min));

}

private void updateTimeTo() throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    time_to = dateFormat.parse(to_day + "/" + to_month + "/" + to_year
            + " " + to_hours + ":" + to_min);

    if (time_from.getTime() <= time_to.getTime()
            && date_from.getTime() <= date_to.getTime()) {

        to_time_builder = new StringBuilder().append(to_hours).append(':')
                .append(to_min);

        to_time.setText(to_time_builder.toString());
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please set proper date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    System.out.println("Thi is in the time to ");

}
```

This is onClick 
{

```
if (v == from_date) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_FROM);
    }

    if (v == to_date) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO);
    }

    if (v == from_time) {
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_FROM);
    }
    if (v == to_time) {
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID_TO);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the Below method in your Activity to update the Date/Time to be shown in the Dialog Box.

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO:
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_FROM:
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudhaker, This worked to an certain extent thanks, later i have done validation when in the to_date is less than the from_date the date wont be set. This throws out a toast, then again when i open the to_date dialog the date is the wrong validated date and not the previous on that was set via settext on the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show from_date by default for to_date, you can change your to_date datepicker to show from date values.

```
case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO:
    Log.i("Date Case", "" + to_day);
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListenerto, from_year,
            from_month, from_day);
```

Or, you can set to_year, to_month and to_day from onDateSet function of from_date picker.

Comment: I ve tried that, after setting it via settext it contains the previous date.